# Using ruamel.yaml, how can I make vars with NEWLINEs be multiline without quotes

Tags: python, json, ruamel.yaml

I am generating YAML which serves as a protocol, and it contains some generated JSON inside of it.

```
import json
from ruamel import yaml
jsonsample = { "id": "123", "type": "customer-account", "other": "..." }
myyamel = {}
myyamel['sample'] = {}
myyamel['sample']['description'] = "This example shows the structure of the message"
myyamel['sample']['content'] = json.dumps( jsonsample, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print yaml.round_trip_dump(myyamel, default_style = None, default_flow_style=False, indent=2, block_seq_indent=2, line_break=0, explicit_start=True, version=(1,1))
```

Then I get this output

```
%YAML 1.1
---
sample:
  content: "{\n    \"other\": \"...\",\n    \"type\": \"customer-account\",\n    \"\
  id\": \"123\"\n}"
description: This example shows the structure of the message
```

Now to me that could look much better 
if I was able to make the multiline rows be formatted starting with a pipe `|`

The output that I want to see is this

```
%YAML 1.1
---
sample:
  content: |
    {    
       "other": "...",
       "type": "customer-account",
       "id": "123"
    }
description: This example shows the structure of the message
```

See how much easier this is to read ...

So how do I solve this in python code ?

Comment: Your YAML files are not exactly the same. Since you use `|` there will be a single trailing newline after the final `}`, to get rid of that you should use `|-` (i.e. block style with the [*strip* block chomping indicator](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
import sys
import json
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)

jsonsample = { "id": "123", "type": "customer-account", "other": "..." }
myyamel = {}
myyamel['sample'] = {}
myyamel['sample']['description'] = "This example shows the structure of the message"
myyamel['sample']['content'] = json.dumps( jsonsample, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.walk_tree(myyamel)

yaml.dump(myyamel, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
%YAML 1.1
---
sample:
  description: This example shows the structure of the message
  content: |-
    {
        "id": "123",
        "type": "customer-account",
        "other": "..."
    }
```

Some notes:

- since you are using a normal dict the order in which your YAML is printed is implementation and key dependent. If you want the order to be fixed to your assignments use:

  ```
    myyamel['sample'] = yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
  ```
- you should never use `print(yaml.round_trip_dump)` if you print the return value, specify the stream to write to, that is more efficient.
- `walk_tree` converts all strings that have a newline in them to block style mode recursively. You can also explicitly do:

  ```
    myyamel['sample']['content'] = yaml.scalarstring.PreservedScalarString(json.dumps( jsonsample, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
  ```

in which case you don't need to call `walk_tree()`

---

Even though you are still working on Python 2, you should start getting used to using the `print` function instead of the `print` statement. For that include at the top of each of your Python files:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: in new ruamel.yaml api, this does not seem to work. It does not use `|` style when there is multiple lines in the string

Comment: @Wang You are doing something wrong, because `walk_tree` still works even when dumping with a `YAML()` instance, I just tried.

Comment: hi @Anthon, instead of dumping to stdout, how can I store the output in a variable with the output as though it was displayed to stdout?

Comment: @sebastianwth That depends on what you want to do with it. Normally the output is a UTF-8 encodied stream so you can capture it using `import ruamel.yaml, io`,  `buf = io.BytesIO()`, `yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()`, `yaml.dump(data, buf)`, and then use `buf.getvalue()` which is an array of bytes. You can use `io.StringIO` as well to get a string, but that is slightly less efficient.