# In Python how to split dictionary key value into multiple lines when dump the dict to Yaml with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a problem when dumping dictionary into YAML file with ruamel.yaml.

Let's assume, this is the dictionary I would dump, where the value of the key is a list of dictionaries.

```
data1 = "blabla-1"
data2 = "blabla-2"

theDict = {"write_files": [{'content': '| ' + data1,
                            'path': '/tmp/f1.txt'},
                           {'content': '| ' + data2,
                            'path': '/tmp/f2.txt'}
                           ]
                           }
```

And this is the result I would like to get:

```
write_files:
-   content: | 
        blabla-1
    path: /tmp/f1.txt
-   content: | 
        blabla-2
    path: /tmp/f2.txt
```

Where the value of "content" key in dict is split into 2 lines.

Unfortunately I got this result instead, where the "content" key value is in the same line where the key is, and also the single quote chars are there.

```
write_files:
-   content: '| blabla-1'
    path: /tmp/f1.txt
-   content: '| blabla-2'
    path: /tmp/f2.txt
```

What should I change in my Python code to get the wanted result?

Here is my Python 3 code:

```
import os
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

data1 = "blabla-1"
data2 = "blabla-2"

theDict = {"write_files": [{'content': '| ' + data1,
                            'path': '/tmp/f1.txt'},
                           {'content': '| ' + data2,
                            'path': '/tmp/f2.txt'}
                           ]
                           }

outputFile = "/tmp/test/yaml_test_out.yaml"

if os.path.isfile(outputFile):
    os.remove(outputFile)

outF = open(outputFile, 'w')

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent = 4
yaml.dump(theDict, outF)
```

Comment: Why do you want/need the multi-line output?

Comment: More importantly, are you aware that the result you would like and the result you are getting **are not equivalent**? I.e., `theDict` cannot be dumped to the form you would like.. Try to load the YAML file you would like to get and compare it with `theDict`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ruamel.yaml, how can I make vars with NEWLINEs be multiline without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068782/using-ruamel-yaml-how-can-i-make-vars-with-newlines-be-multiline-without-quotes)

Comment: `|` isn't part of the value; it's YAML syntax, and should not appear in the original `dict`.

Comment: Whether or not a block scalar (the `|` syntax) is used should be up to YAML encoder, not the data being encoded.

Comment: hello, first of all I would like to thanks for your comments. So my final goal is to make a script for generate cloud_config.yaml with valid data for deploying Virtual machine in Openstack environment. During my manual test I was discovered, VM deployment with "user_data" works only if the "content" represents in multiple-line in the yaml file.